# NSFetchedResultsController count in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am a novice Swift developer coming from an Objective-C background.

I have the following code:

```
class KPCoreDataResultsController: NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

    let entityName: NSString
    var delegate: KPCoreDataResultsDelegate?

    var predicate: NSPredicate {
        get {
            return fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate!
        }
        set {
            fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = newValue            
            do {
                try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    var sortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor!
    var count: NSInteger {
        return (fetchedResultsController.sections!.first!).numberOfObjects
    }

    init(entityName: String, predicate: NSPredicate, sortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor) {
        self.entityName = entityName
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Inside of a custom Core Data Results Controller file to simplify accessing CoreData stuff. When I call the results controller's count property from a table view `(numberOfRowsInSection)`, the app crashes saying:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is the table view code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return accountController.count
}
```

Basically, the code above is giving this error - am I using the !'s wrong? Or what is happening here?

Comment: can you post the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
  return fetchedResultsController.sections![section].numberOfObjects
```

Comment: section isn't a property anywhere in the Results Controller object, only in the Table View itself.

Comment: Usually xCode will use just the first section then (theres always one)

Comment: Ahh see I thought so if I was saying the first section in my code...however when I use "po fetchedResultsController.sections" at that point, nil is returned even though "po fetchedResultsController" does not return nil.

Comment: So it still didn't work? hmm, I could link you my github where I use this code if you wanna go through that?  Because I'm pretty sure using .count isn't the best way to go, I've always used sections. You could try this: return fetchedResultsController.sections![1].numberOfObjects   since you said you don't have sections

Comment: I don't get this at all and it won't help as this isn't the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

count is called before any data (after viewDidLoad) is fetched and so sections and rows are nil. In swift, you may not access nil! if you do, you get an error

---

you do call setPredicate but BEFORE you set fetchedResultController -- so performFetch isn't happening ;)

do a `fetchedResultsController.performFetch() in init or viewDidLoad`